# Using LINQ to project a list to a key / count 2-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, projection

Let's say I have a list of an object like this:

```
var users = new List<User>();
users.Add(new User() { FirstName = "Ek0nomik" });
users.Add(new User() { FirstName = "Ek0nomik" });
users.Add(new User() { FirstName = "Foobar" });
```

I am trying to get a 2-dimensional array that contains the name and the count of that name (for the purpose of returning it as JSON with use in Google Charts) from that list.  This is what the array would contain:

```
["Ek0nomik", 2],
["Foobar", 1]
```

I was initially trying to use `.Select` to project a new object, but that projects for each object within the list so I don't think that method will get me there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
users.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName)
     .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
```

Comment: Excellent example! Is there any way I can get the array without the property names?  In my situation they aren't actually needed.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your question. Is it something like `.Select(x => x.Count())` ?

Comment: Your example results in an array of an anonymous object versus a multidimensional array.  Your example gets me 99% there since I can work with the object array to build what I need; I was just wondering if it was possible to build the multidimensional array immediately.

Comment: What do you use multidim array, Is ,for ex., `users.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());` not enough?

Comment: Maybe this? `users.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName).Select(x => new object[] { x.Key, x.Count()}).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
var asd = users.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName).Select(x => new {Name = "['" + x.Key + "', "+ x.Count() + "]"});
foreach (var t in asd)
{
Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupedUsers = users.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName)
            .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
var dictionary = groupedUsers.ToDictionary(u=>u.Name, u=>u.Count);


var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var output = serializer.Serialize(dictionary);
```

The output will look

```
{"Ek0nomik":2,"Foobar":1}
```

And draw the [charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068349/draw-google-charts-with-json) with JSON.

If you are using Page Methods or an WebService, the lines with JavaScriptSerializer are not needed, only the dictionary to produce that JSON.