# Generating Google Chart With Using Php/Json

Tags: php, json, charts

i tried many ways for generate "Line Google Chart" with php,with or without json i getting "There is no Column" error everytime i have ever tried.Just want to do graps of months.i want to do Counts/Days chart of a month.How can i fix it?

Codes;

```
.
.
.
  $google_array = array();
  foreach($column_day_names["Jan"] as $key => $value) {
    $google_array[] = array($key => $value);
  }
  $json_first=json_encode($google_array);
  echo $json_first . "\xA";
  $json = json_encode($google_array);
  $json = str_replace("{", "[", $json);
  $json = str_replace("}", "]", $json);
  echo $json;
```

First_json output of Jan Array:

> [{"01":1},{"02":1},{"03":6},{"04":1},{"05":3},{"08":1},{"10":1},{"11":1},{"12":1},{"13":1},{"16":1},{"17":1},{"18":2},{"20":1},{"21":2},{"22":2},{"23":1},{"25":1},{"27":2},{"28":1},{"29":1},{"30":3},{"31":1}]

Second Json Output of Jan Array:

> [["01":1],["02":1],["03":6],["04":1],["05":3],["08":1],["10":1],["11":1],["12":1],["13":1],["16":1],["17":1],["18":2],["20":1],["21":2],["22":2],["23":1],["25":1],["27":2],["28":1],["29":1],["30":3],["31":1]

]

Main Array($column_day_names)

```
Array (
    [Jan] => Array
    (
        [01] => 1
        [02] => 1
        [03] => 6
        [04] => 1
        [05] => 3
        [08] => 1
        [10] => 1
        [11] => 1
        [12] => 1
        [13] => 1
        [16] => 1
        [17] => 1
        [18] => 2
        [20] => 1
        [21] => 2
        [22] => 2
        [23] => 1
        [25] => 1
        [27] => 2
        [28] => 1
        [29] => 1
        [30] => 3
        [31] => 1
    )

[Feb] => Array
    (
        [01] => 1
        [03] => 2
        [09] => 1
        [11] => 2
        [12] => 1
        [13] => 1
        [16] => 2
        [17] => 1
        [18] => 1
        [22] => 1
        [24] => 1
    )

[Mar] => Array
    (
        [01] => 2
        [02] => 2
        [07] => 1
        [09] => 1
        [10] => 2
        [11] => 2
        [16] => 2
        [18] => 1
        [21] => 1
        [25] => 3
        [29] => 1
        [30] => 1
        [31] => 1
    )

[Apr] => Array
    (
        [04] => 2
        [06] => 1
        [08] => 1
        [11] => 3
        [12] => 1
        [16] => 1
        [18] => 1
        [20] => 2
        [22] => 1
        [27] => 1
        [29] => 2
        [30] => 1
    )

[May] => Array
    (
        [02] => 1
        [06] => 2
        [07] => 1
        [08] => 1
        [12] => 1
        [21] => 2
        [23] => 2
        [30] => 1
    )

[Jun] => Array
    (
        [01] => 1
        [03] => 3
        [05] => 2
        [06] => 1
        [17] => 2
        [20] => 2
        [24] => 1
        [26] => 1
        [30] => 1
    )

[Jul] => Array
    (
        [10] => 1
        [12] => 2
        [20] => 1
        [22] => 1
        [31] => 1
    )

[Aug] => Array
    (
        [04] => 2
        [06] => 3
        [10] => 2
        [21] => 1
        [26] => 1
    )

[Sep] => Array
    (
        [06] => 6
        [08] => 1
        [14] => 3
    )

[Oct] => Array
    (
        [08] => 1
        [14] => 2
        [20] => 1
        [21] => 1
        [23] => 1
        [24] => 2
        [28] => 1
    )

[Dec] => Array
    (
        [20] => 1
        [21] => 1
        [22] => 1
        [26] => 1
        [31] => 4
    )

)
```

Array of One Month($column_day_names["Jan"]);

```
Array
(
[01] => 1
[02] => 1
[03] => 6
[04] => 1
[05] => 3
[08] => 1
[10] => 1
[11] => 1
[12] => 1
[13] => 1
[16] => 1
[17] => 1
[18] => 2
[20] => 1
[21] => 2
[22] => 2
[23] => 1
[25] => 1
[27] => 2
[28] => 1
[29] => 1
[30] => 3
[31] => 1
)
```

Comment: not clear that is not working. please share you javascript. have you checked other issues like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068349/draw-google-charts-with-json

Comment: check out this full example --> [using ajax to get json data from php and draw google chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955110/5090771)

Comment: i dont understand,i wrote code as a php not javascript.i want to make line google chart with this array i couldnt modify code for me array .